# Glocal\semi-local\Hybride Globale-Local alignment with Python

Tags: sequence-alignment, python

I was looking for a simple way to do a [glocal alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment#Global_and_local_alignments).
The case I have is I have a small sequence which should be find in a bigger one, thus typically a glocal alignment.
Also I can not Install anything on the target machine (Python 3.6 with Biopython is already installed), all I can do is pip install.

My question is : are there any glocal alignment implementation out there ?

I was unable to found one and I don't feel proficient enough with Python yet to implement it myself.

Comment: @winni2k there is also a newer pairwise aligner in `Bio.Align` http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc87

Comment: @ckin, is there any particular reason why you need to perform a glocal alignment?

Comment: @winni2k like I said I have a typically case where you want to do a glocal alignement: I have to align a small sequence against a bigger sequence, and my small should be found within the bigger one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the built-in BioPython pairwise aligner should work for this. You can find a short sequence match in a longer sequence using a global alignment with the right score parameters (`query_end_... = 0`). The other scoring parameters are values that I've found to be good for aligning similar sequences.

Example code:

```
from Bio import Align

aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()
aligner.match_score = 5
aligner.mismatch_score = -9
aligner.mode = 'global'
aligner.target_internal_open_gap_score = -12
aligner.target_internal_extend_gap_score = -3
aligner.target_end_open_gap_score = -12
aligner.target_end_extend_gap_score = -3
aligner.query_internal_open_gap_score = -12
aligner.query_internal_extend_gap_score = -3

# Set the query_end penalties to zero to effectively implement a 'glocal' alignment as described in the question
# These are the default values, so you could skip the next two lines, 
#    but this is relevant to the question, so I'm including them in the example.
aligner.query_end_open_gap_score = 0
aligner.query_end_extend_gap_score = 0
    
alignments = aligner.align("GAACTCGCATCGATGATCCGTGCGCTGAGATCCGCTGACATGATC", "GATCCG")

for a in alignments:
    print(a)
print()
print()

alignments = aligner.align("GAACTCGCATCGATGATCCGTGCGCTGAGATCCGCTGACATGATC", "GATACG")

for a in alignments:
    print(a)
print()
print()

alignments = aligner.align("GAACTCGCATCGATGATCCGTGCGCTGAGATCCGCTGACATGATC", "GATACCG")

for a in alignments:
    print(a)
```